# How to print out a message with the balance of the account After the transaction in a procedure PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My procedure should print out a message with the balance of the account after the transaction is printing the new balance (p_Amount). I don't know how to print the balance of the account after the transaction.

This is a bank system and one of its procedures is a procedure to creates a row in the table withdrawal. I tried using INSERT and it is working but it just add a new row and from here I can not print out a message with the balance of the account after the transaction.

MY TABLEs:

```
Create Table withdrawal (
 WIT_ID                    NUMBER(9)PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
 CUST_ID                   VARCHAR2(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES Customer (Cust_id) ,
 ACC_ID                    NUMBER(8) Not NULL REFERENCES account (ACC_ID),
 Amount                    NUMBER(10,2)  NOT NULL,
 DATE_TIME                 Date Not Null
);
```

My Procedure:

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;

Create or replace procedure do_withdrawal
(
    p_WIT_ID in withdrawal.WIT_ID%type,
    p_cust_id in withdrawal.cust_id%type,
    p_ACC_ID in withdrawal.ACC_ID%type,
    p_AMOUNT in withdrawal.AMOUNT%type,
    p_DATE_TIME in withdrawal.DATE_TIME%type
)
IS
    L_Authority VARCHAR2(4000);
Begin
    SAVEPOINT sp_sptest;

    insert into WITHDRAWAL (WIT_ID,CUST_id,ACC_ID,AMOUNT,DATE_TIME)
    Values                 (p_WIT_ID ,p_cust_id, p_ACC_ID, p_AMOUNT, p_DATE_TIME);

    L_Authority := get_authority(p_cust_id,p_ACC_ID);

    dbms_output.put_line('The Balance is:'|| ' ' || p_Amount );

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK TO sp_sptest;
        dbms_output.put_line('Unauthorized user!');

        COMMIT;
END;
/
```

MY Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_authority
( 
    P_CUST_ID VARCHAR2, 
    P_acc_id VARCHAR2
)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
    P_COUNT NUMBER;  
BEGIN     
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO P_COUNT
    FROM account_owner 
    WHERE CUST_ID = P_CUST_ID AND acc_id=P_acc_id;

    IF (P_COUNT > 0)then
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;

    RETURN 0;
END;
```

The procedure should

-create a row in the table withdrawal.

-Declare an exception called unauthorized.

-Raise unauthorized when the customer doesn't have any authority to the account.(This is working )

-Use the function get_authority to perform the verification.(This is working)

Comment: Not certain, try adding a commit; right above your EXCEPTION. What does your statement look like when executing the proc? I want to say the commit should be happening outside of the proc, maybe the IDE has a pending commit showing?

Comment: Well, you don't specify what exactly you mean by "new balance". Is new balance something that you have to calculate? for example based on initial balance and the new translaction amount. Or it's calculated automtically after transaction and you just to have query that.

Comment: *I can not print out a message with the balance of the account after the transaction.* What do you mean, you can't? How do you call the procedure? Did you `set servoutput on` or the equivalent to enable dbms_output before calling it? (I'm not sure why you enable it before creating the procedure above.) By the way, if my account is empty and I call your procedure to withdraw a million pounds, it will display a message saying my balance is now one million pounds. Will that be legally binding?

Comment: what is the initial balance? and is there any deposits made or just withdrawal?